# Logback external configuration on Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logback

I have Spring Boot application deployed as WAR file on standalone Apache Tomcat.

In order to configure Logback on Windows machine I've created *setenv.bat* file with the following content:

```
set logging.config=<absolute path to logback.xml>
```

I was trying the same for Tomcat deployed on Mac, but the following *setenv.sh* doesn't work:

```
logging.config=<absolute path to logback.xml>
```

I've also tried set *logging.config* variable using *export* command:

```
export logging.config=<absolute path to logback.xml>
```

but result is the same - log files aren't created.
Any ideas what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have found your answer somewhere. But what I have done is that in conf/catalina.properties, point to the logback config file as follows:

```
logging.config=${catalina.base}/conf/logback-spring.xml
```

I don't do anything in setenv.bat.